# Error: No parameterless constructor defined for this object

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

*I am trying to use Action-[HttpPost] in my ASP MVC project however the Post Action doesn't seems to work.After Submit button Page will showing Error.*

Following is my model:

```
public class bcSlider
{
    public int sliderID { get; set; }
    public string sliderImage { get; set; }
}
```

Following is my ManageOperations:

```
 public class MngSlider
 {
  public int insertSlider(bcSlider obj)
    {
        int condition = 0;
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ospDB"].ConnectionString);
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertConfrence", con);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SliderImage", obj.ImageName);
            if (con.State.Equals(ConnectionState.Closed))
                con.Open();
            condition = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            if (condition > 0)
            {
                return 1;
            }
            else
            {
                return 0;
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
  }
```

Following is Controller:

```
public class AdminSliderController : Controller
{
    bcSlider modelSlider = new bcSlider();
    MngSlider objSlider = new MngSlider();

  //---------------INSERT---------------//
    // GET: /AdminSlider/AddSlider
    public ActionResult AddSlider()
    {
        bcSlider mSlider = new bcSlider();
        return View(mSlider);
    }


    // POST: /AdminSlider/AddSlider
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddSlider(HttpPostedFile file, bcSlider mSlider)
    {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //File Available Verification
                if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  //FileName
                    string fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(fileName); //FileExtension

                    //Extension Verification
                    if (fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".jpeg" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".png" || fileExtension.ToLower() == ".pdf" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".JEPG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PNG" || fileExtension.ToUpper() == ".PDF")
                    {
                        //FileSize Verification
                        int length = file.ContentLength;
                        if (length <= 1000)
                        {
                            string filepath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/ImagesDirectory/"), fileName); //FilePath
                            file.SaveAs(filepath);
                            objSlider.insertSlider(mSlider); //Insert to DB
                            ViewBag.Message = "<script>alert('File  Inserted Successfully !')</script>";
                            ModelState.Clear();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ViewBag.SizeMessage = "<script>alert('Size Should be of 1MB !')</script>";
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ViewBag.ExtensionMessage = "<script>alert('File Not Supported !')</script>";
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    ViewBag.Message = "<script>alert('Invalid File !')</script>";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                ViewData["result"] = "Registration Not Successful";
            }
                   return RedirectToAction("AddSlider");

    }
   }
 }
```

Following is htmlcs:

```
@model OspWebsite.Models.bcSlider

@{
ViewBag.Title = "AddSlider";
Layout = "~/Views/Shared/LayoutAdmin.cshtml";
}

<div class="content-header">

<!-- Page Name -->
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <h1 class="m-0 text-dark">Slider</h1>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <ol class="breadcrumb float-sm-right">
                <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li class="breadcrumb-item active">Slider</li>
            </ol>
        </div><!-- /.col -->
    </div><!-- /.row -->
</div>
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.Message)
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.SizeMessage)
@Html.Raw(ViewBag.ExtensionMessage)
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSlider", "AdminSlider", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<!-- Input Forms -->
<div class="row">
    <div class="offset-md-1 mt-5 col-md-10">
        <div class="card card-success">
            <div class="card-header">
                <h3 class="card-title">Add New Slider</h3>
                <div class="card-tools">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="maximize"><i class="fas fa-expand"></i></button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-tools -->
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-header -->
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 ">
                            <label for="inputEmail3"  class="col-sm-4 control-label">Select Slider</label>
                            <div class="custom-file">
                                <label class="custom-file-label" for="exampleInputFile"></label>
                                <input type="file" name="sliderImage" value=@Model.sliderImage class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- /.card-body -->
            </div><div class="card-footer">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Upload</button>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default float-right">Cancel</button>
            </div>
            <!-- /.card-footer -->
            <!-- /.card-body -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.card -->
    </div>
    <!-- /.col -->
</div>
   }

 </div>
```

The GET Action is Calling  But POST Action is Showing Error.
i am inserting Image in Database.

Comment: Hi, What is the error you are getting? and on what line is the error happening?, looking at your code, this line `objSlider.insertSlider(mSlider);`, I don't see it working the way you intended

Comment: i Click on Submit Button Then Page getting Error "No parameterless constructor defined for this object.".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having the error because of the parameter you are passing in the controller `HttpPostedFile`

```
HttpPostedFileBase and HttpPostedFile
```

are definitely not the same.

Change your method to

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddSlider(HttpPostedFileBase sliderImage, bcSlider mSlider)
{
     //your code here.
}
```

**Notice** that I used `sliderImage` because that was also what you have in your form.

**Again** Your form, which I don't know if it was a typo error is setting the value of a file-input

```
<input type="file" name="sliderImage" value=@Model.sliderImage class="custom-file-input" id="exampleInputFile">
```

**You are not supposed to do that.**

*Again* and on lighter note, if it is also not a typo, you don't have any attribute in you class `obj.ImageName` but you have the below in your `insertSlider` method

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SliderImage", obj.ImageName);
```

**For more on HttpPostedFileBase and HttpPostedFile and see** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24910982/httppostedfilebases-relationship-to-httppostedfilewrapper)

That's all for now.

Comment: Thanks Buddy.My Code is Working :D

Comment: I Click to Accept Your Answer But Stackoverflow .Popup the Message That
"Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Hi @Developer_Ltd this is [how to accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.