# File is not uploading in ASP.Net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Hi to all of you I am facing a problem on uploading a file and saving it into a folder here is my view

```
<div class="admin-empty-dashboard">
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadResumes", "Employee", new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <div class="icon">
        <i class="ion-ios-book-outline"></i>
    </div>

    <h4>Welcome @Model.FullName!</h4>
    <p>@ViewBag.Error</p>
    <div class="form-group bootstrap-fileinput-style-01">
        <label>Upload Resume</label>
        <input type="file" name="file" required="required" class="btn btn-primary" style="margin-left:265px" accept="application/msword,text/plain, application/pdf">
        <span class="font12 font-italic">** File must not bigger than 2MB</span>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="name" class="btn btn-primary" value="UploadResumes" />
}

</div>
```

and here is my controllers action problem is that it HttpPostedFileBase object value is always null and i ran Request.Files.Count it's also giving me zero where is problem?

```
public ActionResult UploadResumes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
    if (Session["UserID"] != null && Session["UserName"] != null && Session["EmployeeID"] != null)
    {
        int id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["EmployeeID"]);
        string[] allowedExtenssions = new string[] { ".pdf", ".doc", ".docx" };
        string cvPath = "~/cvs/Employee_cvs/";
        if (!Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(cvPath)))
            Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(cvPath));

        MyDbContext db=new MyDbContext();
        tblEmployee employee = (from s in db.tblEmployees where s.UserId == id select s).FirstOrDefault();

        // HttpPostedFileBase cv = Request.Files["CV"];
        if (file != null)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {

                string ext = Path.GetExtension(file.FileName);
                if (allowedExtenssions.Contains(ext.ToLower()))
                {
                    string fileName = DateTime.Now.Ticks + ext;
                    string filePath = cvPath + fileName;
                    string serverPath = Server.MapPath(filePath);
                    file.SaveAs(serverPath);
                    employee.cvUrl = filePath;
                }

            }
            ViewBag.Error = "Some Error Occured";
        }

        return RedirectToAction("Dashboard");

    }
    else
    {
        return RedirectToAction("Login", "User");
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is MVC HttpPostedFileBase always null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38713956/why-is-mvc-httppostedfilebase-always-null)

Comment: Dear Please solve my problem I shall be very thankful to all of you

Comment: Have you add [HttpPost] before your controller action?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update like below and check

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadResumes", "Employee",FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

}
```

Also

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult UploadResumes(HttpPostedFileBase file)
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your parameters on your controller to

```
public ActionResult UploadResumes(Model yourModel, HttpHostedFileBase file)
```

Answer (score 0):

In most of my controllers that require a file for upload, are usually array based. Make you function parameters an array like this:

```
public ActionResult UploadResumes(HttpPostedFileBase[] files){
}
```