# File Upload ASP.NET MVC Not Working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload

I have tried my best however `HttpPostedFileBase filee` is always `null`

Controller Action

```
 public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase filee)
        {
            try
            {
                if (filee.ContentLength > 0)
                {
                    string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(filee.FileName);
                    string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);
                    filee.SaveAs(_path);
                }
                ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";
                return View();
            }
            catch
            {
                ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";
                return View();
            }
        }
```

Razor View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "UploadFile";
}

<h2>UploadFile</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{

    <div>
        @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

        @ViewBag.Message

    </div>


}
```

Comment: Because the name of the file input is `file` not `filee`. They need to match.

Comment: Have a look at [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8551621/3814721)

Comment: Any good reason? for this. We have always have choice to name the instance according to our desire. 


Employee employee=new Employee();

Comment: Please mention the improvement if you going to vote down my question. It's not enough for a  individual to learn what is wrong? By just down voting the question.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Thanks for help highly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Either change the name of parameter in `public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase filee)` to `public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file)` or change the input name `@Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file" })` to `@Html.TextBox("filee", "", new { type = "file" })`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use same name of yor input field as your HttpPostedFileBase object name while you are working on loosly type view !

Example :

```
    @{
        ViewBag.Title = "UploadFile";
    }

    <h2>UploadFile</h2>

    @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
    {

        <div>
            @Html.TextBox("filee", "", new { type = "file" }) <br />
            <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

            @ViewBag.Message

        </div>

}
```

Or If you don't want to use same names ? 
you just have to use a tightly coupled view  type view

Tightly
Example:

```
@model PROJECTNAME.Models.MODELNAME

        @{
            ViewBag.Title = "UploadFile";
        }

        <h2>UploadFile</h2>

        @using (Html.BeginForm("UploadFile", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {

            <div>
                @Html.TextBox(model => model.YOURCOLUMNNAME , "", new { type = "file" }) <br />
                <input type="submit" value="Upload" />

                @ViewBag.Message

            </div>

    }
```