# MVC HttpPostedFilebase is always retuen null

Tags: c#, razor, file-upload, asp.net-mvc-5, httppostedfilebase

I am trying to upload a file in asp.net mvc 5 application by using the following code.

Please see the cshtml and model class and guide me what I am missing. It always return null for HttpPostedFilebase .

cshtml :

```
<form action="@Url.Action("send-message", "users", new { area = "security" })" class="form-horizontal" method="POST" data-async data-target="#send-message-modal" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { placeholder = "Select the recipient...", @class = "form-control form-group-margin" })

            @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.RecipientId)
        </div>
    </div>

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Title, new { placeholder = "Enter a subject", @class = "form-control" })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Title)


    @Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Message, new { placeholder = "Enter your message", @class = "form-control", rows = 5 })
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Message)

    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileNew, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", name= "FileNew" })
    <br/>

    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FileNew)

    <div class="panel-footer text-right no-padding-hr no-padding-b">
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SendMessageModel
{

    [Display(Name = "Recipient")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Recipient")]
    public int RecipientId { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }

    public bool IsSent { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Text)]
    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Subject")]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public HttpPostedFileBase FileNew { get; set; }
}
```

Mvc Action :

```
[ActionName("send-message")]
    [HttpPost]

    public ActionResult SendMessage(SendMessageModel model)
    {

    }
```

Comment: How do you submit your form? Changing <button class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button> to <input type="submit" value="Send message" class="btn btn-primary" /> might help.

Answer (score 1):

In View page, you can add the below line of code

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("UploadFile","Upload", FormMethod.Post, new { 
enctype="multipart/form-data"}))  
{    
<div>  
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new {  type= "file"}) <br />  

    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />  

    @ViewBag.Message  

</div>    
}
```

and in controller

```
public ActionResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, SendMessageModel model)  
    {  
        try  
        {  
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)  
            {  
                string _FileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);  
                string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/UploadedFiles"), _FileName);  
                file.SaveAs(_path);  
            }  
            ViewBag.Message = "File Uploaded Successfully!!";  
            return View();  
        }  
        catch  
        {  
            ViewBag.Message = "File upload failed!!";  
            return View();  
        }  
     }
```

so you can get the file name and in the Uploadedfolder your file will be saved.
Hope it can be helpful to you

Answer (score 0):

Add the HttpPostedFileBase parameter in method.

```
public ActionResult SendMessage(SendMessageModel model, HttpPostedFileBase FileNew)
{}
```

Comment: No, It still returns null.

Comment: Edit form same this anwser https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8551528/httppostedfilebase-always-return-null-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: From my cshtml file and also ViewModel , you can see it, I have the following     @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileNew, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", name= "FileNew" })
Form field name is  : FileNew  and model property is also FileNew

Comment: Change  @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FileNew, new { type = "file", @class = "form-control", name= "FileNew" }) to  <input type="file" name="FileNew"  />

Comment: No, still returns null.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.